# How to apply DRL to solve a problem that involves mixed discrete-continuous action spaces where the action's size changes over time?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, continuous-action-spaces, discrete-action-spaces

I have a reinforcement learning problem where a possible action is a probability vector $[p_1\ldots,p_n]$ of size $n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$, where each element $p_i$ of the vector is between $0$ and $1$ and the sum of the elements of the vector is $1$, $\sum_ip_i=1$.

At each step, the RL agent should choose the value of $n$ and the elements of the vector. You can see this problem as a resource allocation problem between different machines where the agent should first choose the machines to which it should allocate resources (i.e., chooses $n$). Then, it should partition the resources. among those $n$ machines.

I have two questions.

The first one is: How can I solve this problem using DRL? In fact, as you see it is a mixed discrete-continuous action RL problem where the action size can change at each step. Do you have any useful idea or reference (code or paper) that I can use to solve this kind of problem? I thought of making it fully continuous RL problem, but I still do not see how...

My second question comes after trying to make the problem fully discrete problem. Since I have probabilities as actions, I thought that I can make them as proportions and thus discretize the action. So, the RL agent has to choose $n$ and the number of resources to allocate to each machine $1,\ldots,n$. The problem here is the size of the action space. In my problem, there are very large numbers of discrete actions according to the way I partition the resources. I can easily have 5 billions discrete actions.

Can DRL really solve such discrete action problem?

Comment: Is there a reasonable max $n$, and are there any assumed or expected properties of the vector such that similar vectors should obtain similar rewards? Also, what is the state like, and the state progression?

Comment: Yes, a reasonable value of max $n$ is $\{2,3,4\}$ out of $N$ machines. I don't know how to define similar vectors. I think if they are very close to each others like having $p_i=0.12$ and $p_i=0.13$, then they must have similar rewards. Because $p_i=0.12$ and $p_i=0.13$ means that some proportions of the resources are assigned to machine $i$ and thus almost the same number of resources are assigned to $i$. My state is the 3D positions of the $N$ machines so it can be seen as a continuous space $[0,1]^{3N}$.

Comment: Do the machines change position based on the action choice?

Comment: No, the position changes according to some mobility model (according to the transition from state to state).

Comment: So the action choice has no effect at all on what happens next? It is just to collect some immediate reward? Sorry to keep asking these questions, but this is important to clarify the nature of the problem. I'm starting to suspect you don't have a full RL problem here, which opens up other possibilities. So as well as clarifying/confirming my questions above, could you state whether your goal with the question is to ask about this specific issue in an RL context, or whether you are trying to find any solution to train your predictive model for maximising reward?